# In Swift 5, how do I display the raw bits returned from range.UpperBound or range.LowerBound in a readable way (with ints)?

Tags: swift, printing, range, swift5, swift-playground

I am starting to experiment in Swift Playgrounds to familiarize myself with the language. To repeat my question: In Swift 5, how do I display the raw bits returned from range.UpperBound or range.LowerBound in a readable way (with ints)?

As an example, let's say I have a string `var myStr = "Hello World!"` and I was looking to see if a 'substring' exists in myStr in order. If it does, then I would like to print the indices of that found range:

```
    var myStr = "Hello World!"
    if let rangeFound = myStr.range(of: "ello"){
        print(rangeFound) //Im getting: Index(_rawBits: 65536)..<Index(_rawBits: 327680)
        print("Found ello from \(rangeFound.lowerBound) to \(rangeFound.upperBound)")
        //prints: Found ello from Index(_rawBits: 65536) to Index(_rawBits: 327680)
    }
```

Instead of printing the raw bits I would like to print the readable indices ..."from 1 to 4"
I am not trying to use these numbers in another range, only trying to print the readable indices. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An Unicode character can consist of more than one byte so an index cannot be simply  `Int`.

A workaround to get the integer indices is a conversion to `NSRange`

```
let myStr = "Hello World!"
if let rangeFound = myStr.range(of: "ello"){
    let nsRange = NSRange(rangeFound, in: myStr)
    print("Found ello from \(nsRange.location) to \(nsRange.location + nsRange.length - 1)")
}
```